# Roll over index if out of range (Python 3)

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access the neighbouring elements (above, below, left and right) in a square 2D list. When the element I'm looking at is on an 'edge' of the 2D list, however, it will try to access a list index that doesn't exist. Here's the code I'm using:

```
surroundings = [
                my_2D_array[currentY+1][currentX],
                my_2D_array[currentY-1][currentX],
                my_2D_array[currentY][currentX+1],
                my_2D_array[currentY][currentX-1]
]
```

How do I get it to 'roll over', so in a list `l` with 3 items, instead of throwing an error accessing `l[3]`, it would simply access `l[0]` instead?

Comment: `index % 3` should do what you want. this will also handle the negative indices corretly and have them 'wrap around'.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Could you provide a usage example?

Comment: `array[index % 3]`: no matter what (integer) `index` is, `index % 3` will be one of `0, 1, 2` (or more generally: `index % n` will be one of `0, 1, 2,..., n-1`).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist So, I'd do `my_2D_array[currentY][(currentX+1)%width]` where `width` is the number of items in each nested array?

Comment: that's what i'd suggest! good luck!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist That takes me further, but in my w20 h15 list, when I get to `l[14][0]`, I get `list index out of range`. If you don't mind helping me some more, could this be moved to chat to discuss further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180587/discussion-between-theo-c-and-hiro-protagonist).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to perform a 'roll over', or 'wrap around' as I'd say, is to use modulus:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[3 % len(x)]
1
>>> 3 % len(x)  # 3 % 3 is 0
0
```

If you are 100% sure the length of the list is constant, simply hard-code the modulus right-hand-side value into your code:

```
x[index % 3]
```

This is because you could describe modulus as removing as many multiples of the RHS number from the LHS one, returning the vale left over. So, `x % y` returns the remainder after (floor) dividing `x` by `y`.